# What movie is playing in the theater in Conspiracy Theory?

Tags: identify-this-movie, conspiracy-theory

There is a relatively brief scene in Conspiracy Theory where the main character (Jerry/Mel Gibson) runs into a theater.

There are a couple of shots where you can plainly see what is being played on the screen. What movie is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [IMDB's trivia section](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118883/trivia) and [this](http://www.eeggs.com/items/8356.html) the movie showed is [Ladyhawke](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089457/combined). I can't remember personally and don't own the DVD, so I cannot check this statements.